# Looping through object literal with nested functions

Tags: javascript, loops, object-literal, for-in-loop

I'm trying to loop through an object literal and select just one of the keys and return it's value, which will be a function.  My problem is, that I can't get the loop to return just one value - it always returns all of the values (functions).  I noticed that if I nest the function inside of the object literal (see foo), then it works better, but still not looping through.

[Here is the JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexflores67/r130osnt/#&togetherjs=2Kf9VTlBts).

```
var functions = {
   blah: blah(),
   foo: function() { console.log("foo"); }
};


for(var key in functions){
   if(functions[key] == 'foo') {
   console.log("hello"); //if functions contains the key 'foo' say hi
  }
}
function blah () {alert("blah")};

functions.foo();
```

Comment: I don't see what the code has to do with your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was new to programming. I thought it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking for the key, you are checking a string against a function.

```
for(var key in functions){
    if (key==="foo") {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

another way is to use Object.keys()

```
var keys = Object.keys(functions);
if (keys.indexOf("foo")>-1) {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Comment: There was a another post where there was an argument over using === vs == and I did not realize I fat fingered it. ;) Thought that hold argument was coming to a new thread. (3.5 more hours until 5)

Answer (score 1):

```
in your condition if(functions[key] == 'foo')

the functions[key] returns a function. the key itself is already a literal that can be compare to 'foo'

var functions = {
   blah: blah(),
   foo: function() { console.log("foo"); }
};


for(var key in functions){
   if(key == 'foo') {
   console.log("hello"); //if functions contains the key 'foo' say hi
  }
}
function blah () {alert("blah")};

functions.foo();
```